# swap space for performance

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How will a swap partition/file affect the system?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/how-will-a-swap-partition-file-affect-the-system)

so what do you think, is it better to use swap space or not for small memory phone such as T-Mobile G1 to increase responsiveness and overall performance?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/how-will-a-swap-partition-file-affect-the-system

Answer (score 3):

I found it better to use [compcache](http://code.google.com/p/compcache/) rather than swap. Basically -- a section of RAM is reserved and used as a swap space with compression. Even with the performance hit from compression, it was sufficiently faster than conventional swap that it was a clear-cut winner in performance.

CyanogenMod supports it (Settings > CM Settings > Performance, I believe). I'm sure other mods include it as well, but I am not familiar with them.